# JDBC PreparedStatement.setString throws Out Of Bounds exception

Tags: java, sqlitejdbc

I have a simple PreparedStatement string like this:

```
INSERT INTO albums (name, date) VALUES (?, ?)
```

I have created the table with this:

```
CREATE TABLE "albums" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "date"  TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

This is the simplest example I could write:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    Connection dbConnection;
    String sqlAlbumQuery = "INSERT INTO albums (name, date) VALUES (?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement statement;

    try {
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:plswork.sqlite");
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to establish connection: " + e);
        return;
    }

    try {
        statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlAlbumQuery);

        statement.setString(0, "some album"); //StatementTest.java:40
        statement.setString(1, "2012"); //StatementTest.java:41

        statement.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create album: " + e);
    }
}
```

and this is the message I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.sqlite.core.CorePreparedStatement.batch(CorePreparedStatement.java:130)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.setString(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:417)
    at statementtest.StatementTest.main(StatementTest.java:40)
C:\Users\notangryatall\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.3\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\notangryatall\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.3\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
```

I am using Netbeans 11.3 with JDK 1.8 and sqlite-jdbc-3.30.1.

I tried changing to JDK 13, tried using older sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1, tried adding semicolon to end of the `sqlAlbumQuery`, tried using `statement.executeQuery()` instead of `statement.executeUpdate()` and tried Google but still couldn't find anything.

Comment: Try setting parameters 1 and 2 instead of 0 and 1.

Comment: Oh, that solved the problem, I totally forgot that thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the PreparedStatement docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String)):

> the first parameter is 1, the second is 2, ...

So you should be calling `setString(1,...)` and `setString(2,...)` instead of `setString(0,...)` and `setString(1,...)`

Answer (score 3):

Issue is here:

```
statement.setString(0, "some album"); //StatementTest.java:40
```

Prepare statement index starts from 1(from PreparedStatement interface):

```
@param parameterIndex the first parameter is 1, the second is 2, ...
```